# Combining multiple rows into a single row SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this.

```
|InvID| Client | Group | PricedDate | TotalFee | RepricedFee | CompanyFee|
|1    | A      | A.1   | 02-24-2020 | 100      | 80          | 8         |
|1    | A      | A.1   | 01-05-2020 | 100      | 75          | 1         |
|2    | A      | A.1   | 01-09-2020 | 100      | 60          | 1         |
|3    | B      | B.1   | 01-11-2020 | 150      | 95          | 10        |
|4    | B      | B.1   | 01-01-2020 | 100      | 55          | 11        |
|4    | B      | B.1   | 02-01-2020 | 100      | 90          | 10        |
```

I need to display a single row based on the latest PricedDate and Sum of Company Fee

```
|InvID| Client | Group | PricedDate | TotalFee | RepricedFee | CompanyFee|
|1    | A      | A.1   | 02-24-2020 | 100      | 80          | 9         |
|2    | A      | A.1   | 01-09-2020 | 100      | 60          | 1         |
|3    | B      | B.1   | 01-11-2020 | 150      | 95          | 10        |
|4    | B      | B.1   | 02-01-2020 | 100      | 90          | 21        |
```

Comment: please put based on what you have to pick each column. i.e. TotalFee, what is if they were two different amounts

Comment: Yes, please tell us which column values must match so you make them one row. Then tell us the rules you want applied on the other columns. The SUM for `CompanyFee` probably. But the *latest* or the *least* `RepricedFee`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I have edited the question with more examples.

Comment: Okay, so it seems to be the latest row *per InvID* you are talking about. The sample data would have been much easier to read, did the rows contain different data for client, group and total fee. I've posted an answer. Yogesh Sharma shows a good alternative in their answer. (You can remove `t.client` from the `PARTITION BY` clauses, though, if it's about one result row per InvID only.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it the latest row per `InvID` you want? I would probably just get the maximum date and the sum in an aggregation query and then join that row:

```
select
  t.invid,
  t.client,
  t.group,
  t.priceddate,
  t.totalfee,
  t.repricedfee,
  agg.sum_fee as companyfee
from
(
  select invid, max(priceddate) as max_date, sum(companyfee) as sum_fee
  from mytable
  group by invid
) agg
join mytable t on t.invid = agg.invid and t.priceddate = agg.max_date
order by t.invid;
```

Answer (score 0):

just do aggregation

```
select invId,client,[group],max(priceddate),max(Totalfee),min(repricedFee),sum(companyfee)
from table 
group by invId,client,[group]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
select *
       , (select sum(CompanyFee) from my_table mt3 group by InvID) CompanyFee
from my_table mt1
where mt1.PricedDate = (select max(mt2.PricedDate) 
                        from my_table mt2
                        where mt2.InvID = mt1.InvID);
```

This part will make sure your data is from the row that has the largest `PricedDate` :

```
mt1.PricedDate = (select max(mt2.PricedDate) 
                  from my_table mt2
                  where mt2.InvID = mt1.InvID)
```

Also, if it is not enough to group by `InvID` only you can add other columns there.

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5eab1664302b38296e71c9b1f0b01a1f)

Comment: Hi @RiteshMaharjan has any of this anwsers helped you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
declare @CompanyFee= select sum(CompanyFee) from table1
select InvID,Client,Group,PricedDate,TotalFee,RepricedFee,@CompanyFee from table1
       where priceddate=max(priceddate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select *
from my_table mt1
cross apply (
    select CompanyFee=sum(CompanyFee) from my_table mt3  where mt3.invid=mt1.invid
) as CompanyFeeTbl                    
where mt1.PricedDate = (select max(mt2.PricedDate) 
                        from my_table mt2
                        where mt2.InvID = mt1.InvID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function :

```
select t.InvID, t.Client, t.Group, t.PricedDate, 
       t.TotalFee, t.RepricedFee, t.SumCompanyFee as CompanyFee
from(select t.*, sum(t.companyfee) over (partition by t.client, t.invId) as SumCompanyFee,
            row_number() over (partition by t.client, t.invId order by t.PricedDate desc) as seq
     from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```